# What is the correct romaji/kanji for a phrase that sounds like “fui cabaru”

Tags: kanji, rōmaji, phonetics

A japanese Aikido master used the term that sounds like “fui cabaru” or the “up” position of the a sword. I also believe it means something like “the place your hat goes”.

Can you tell me the correct romaji and kanji for this phrase?[image: upward position of the sword]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With minimal research, it seems like it's [[振り]{fu・ri}[かぶる]{ka・bu・ru}](https://jisho.org/search/%E6%8C%AF%E3%82%8A%E3%81%8B%E3%81%B6%E3%82%8B).

かぶる could also be written as 被る, but in this compound, I'm seeing it mostly in hiragana.